# Sparx Enterprise Architect JScript support String methods

Tags: javascript, jscript

I'm not a Javascript or JScript expert as will be evident in my question. I'm trying to compare strings in JScript, but I can't seem to find the right methods. According to what I've read JScript should be almost identical to Javascript, but when I call a method on a String object such as the includes() method I get an error that says "Object doesn't support this property or method". For example:

```
var Name = new String(currentElement.Name);             
if(Name.includes("authorized user") == true)
{
    ...// do some work here     
}
```

Error says the object (Name) does not support the method (includes).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you are checking in IE , there is no support for includes in string. you can create  a pollyfill. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill

Comment: JScript is almost identical to an older version of JS, which predates `includes()`.  You can use a polyfill.

Comment: Far as I can tell, EA uses spidermonkey as the embedded javascript engine. So it "should" be ECMA262 compliant, and "should" support the includes method, but I may be wrong. I am having this exact same problem right now. Is there an embedded string-contains method in the js engine of EA (currently 14+).